# In this code I added notification with actions but i am not getting actions why?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

// Specify the notification types.

```
    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound]

    // Specify the notification actions.
    let stopAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    stopAction.identifier = Id.stopIdentifier
    stopAction.title = "Dismiss"
    stopAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.background
```

//        stopAction.isDestructive = false
//        stopAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false

```
    let snoozeAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    snoozeAction.identifier = Id.snoozeIdentifier
    snoozeAction.title = "Snooze"
    snoozeAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.background
```

//        snoozeAction.isDestructive = false
//        snoozeAction.isAuthenticationRequired = false

```
    let actionsArray = [UIUserNotificationAction](arrayLiteral: snoozeAction, stopAction)
    let actionsArrayMinimal = [UIUserNotificationAction](arrayLiteral: snoozeAction, stopAction)

    // Specify the category related to the above actions.
    let alarmCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
    alarmCategory.identifier = "myAlarmCategory"
    alarmCategory.setActions(actionsArray, for: .default)
    alarmCategory.setActions(actionsArrayMinimal, for: .minimal)


    let categoriesForSettings = Set(arrayLiteral: alarmCategory)
    // Register the notification settings.
    let newNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: categoriesForSettings)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(newNotificationSettings)
```

Please check above code give me solutions.....!

Comment: Here I used Alarm in github.